# Why does Process.runSync terminate early on Windows?

Tags: flutter, dart

According to [Process.runSync](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process/runSync.html) documentation

> Starts a process and runs it to completion.

But, when you run

```
ProcessResult results = Process.runSync('dir', []);
```

The `results.stdout` only contains the first line "Volume in drive C has no label.". The rest of the content is not there.

But, if you inspect the execution, using

```
Process.start('dir', []).then(Process p) {
  p.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder)
    .listen(data) {
      print(data);
    } 
});
  p.exitCode.then((exitCode) {
    print('exit code: $exitCode');
  });
```

You will see the full output is there, but spliced into a few chunks, and there is only one normal exit signaling.

It seems `Process.runSync` doesn't do what it was advertised on Windows platform. FYI: I also tried simple test on MacOS, it works as expected. I haven't tested this on Linux yet.

Answer (score 0):

This actually is not a real problem. It was a confusing vscode UI display. See more detail at https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/issues/700#issuecomment-605589184